# running 8mb of sql code in wamp?

Tags: sql, mysql, wamp

i have about 8mb of sql code i need to run. it looks like this:

```
/*
MySQL Data Transfer
Source Host: 10.0.0.5
Source Database: jnetdata
Target Host: 10.0.0.5
Target Database: jnetdata
Date: 5/26/2009 12:27:33 PM
*/

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for chavrusas
-- ----------------------------
CREATE TABLE `chavrusas` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `date_created` datetime default NULL,
  `luser_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `ruser_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `luser_type` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `ruser_type` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `SessionDay` varchar(250) default NULL,
  `SessionTime` datetime default NULL,
  `WeeklyReminder` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `reminder_phone` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `calling_card` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `notes` mediumtext,
  `ended` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `end_date` datetime default NULL,
  `initiated_by_student` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `initiated_by_volunteer` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `student_general_reason` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `volunteer_general_reason` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `student_reason` varchar(250) default NULL,
  `volunteer_reason` varchar(250) default NULL,
  `student_nli` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `volunteer_nli` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `jnet_initiated` tinyint(1) default '0',
  `belongs_to` varchar(50) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5913 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for tbluseravailability
-- ----------------------------
CREATE TABLE `tbluseravailability` (
  `availability_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `weekday_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `timeslot_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`availability_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=10865 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for tblusers
-- ----------------------------
CREATE TABLE `tblusers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `
```

etc

how do i run it on http://www.wampserver.com/en/download.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the mysql.exe in your wamp installation, then run

```
 mysql.exe -u username -p password database < textfile.sql
```

Comment: can you give me an example? it doesnt wokr fo rme

Comment: You are using the command line right?
Did you replace "username" with your mysql username? 
Did you replace "password" with your mysql password?
Did you replace "textfile.sql" with your 8mb sql file?
What isn't working? what error are you getting?

Comment: Oh yeah, make sure you replace database with the name of the mysql database you want to import into.

Answer (score 4):

see [Executing SQL Statements from a Text File](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/batch-commands.html)

Answer (score 1):

Presuming that WAMP means Windows, Apache, MySQL, Perl/Php, you would use the MySQL command line client to apply the SQL script.

The process is documented here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-batch-commands.html

If Wampserver installs MySQL in the normal place, the `mysql` client will be found somewhere such as `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysql` .

Comment: hold on joe and longneck, i want to only use wamp to do this. i dont want to download mysql yet. im just a beginner. unless you want to explain to me how i can connect mysql to wamp

Comment: the M in wamp is Mysql. no mysql, no wamp.

Comment: sooo, what is that link for? wampserver includes "MySQL 5.1.36".

Comment: wampserver is just on c:\wamp, what should i do to get this code rnuning?